# Debian jessie 8.5 doesn't detect wireless

Tags: debian, wifi

I finished the installation of Debian Jessie 8.5,
but the system doesn't detect the wireless.
My wireless is hidden, have password with wpa psk/wpa2 psk
and I am using the Xfce desktop environment.

`ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:d2:44:c1:02:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5727 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 062a:4102 Creative Labs 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b736]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: It may be that your firmware is missing : some devices need a proprietary firmware, which will not be automatically installed without you knowing and meaning it. Could you edit your question adding the output (in the terminal) of the commands `ip a` to see whether the device can be configured, `lsusb` and `lspci` to see the model in case it is not. In the last two, look for `Ethernet controller`.

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: @Sona , To get a good question ,Please , Clic on edit http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/297585/edit and add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` .

Comment: lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b736]
        Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

Answer (score 3):

You need to install [`firmware-realtek`](https://packages.debian.org/fr/jessie/firmware-realtek)

> Binary firmware for Realtek wired and wireless network adapters
>
> This package contains the binary firmware for some Ethernet adapters with the RTL8111/RTL8168 chips supported by the r8169 driver; and wireless network cards with the RTL8188, RTL8192, RTL8712, RTL8723 and RTL8821 chips supported by the r8192_pci, r8192s_usb, r8712u, rtl8188eu, rtl8192ce, rtl8192cu, rtl8192de, rtl8192se, rtl8723ae, rtl8723au, **rtl8723be** and rtl8821ae drivers.

The needed driver is :`rtl8723be`

1) Connect throught ethernet

Add `non-free` repo to your `sources.list`:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then add the following lines:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Update and install realtek drivers

```
apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-realtek
```

If your connexion keep disconnecting type the following command :

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

2) Without internet connexion:

Download [`firmware-realtek_0.43_all.deb`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/firmware-realtek/download) , using your archive manager extract `rtl8723befw.bin` from `/lib/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin` and copy it to `/lib/firmware/rtlwifi` :

```
cp rtl8723befw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
```

Reload the driver :

```
modprobe -rv rtl8723be
modprobe -v rtl8723be
```