# wifi interface: unavailable "Realtek RTL8723BE" | Debian 10

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, networkmanager

I have recently Debian 10 on my ASUS Laptop and no wireless network is connected. Here is the output of the command nmcli :

```
enp2s0f2: connected to Wired connection 1
    "Realtek RTL810xE"
    ethernet (r8169), MAC Adress, hw, mtu 1500
    ip4 default
    inet4 192.168.1.7/24
    route4 0.0.0.0/0
    route4 0.0.0.0/0
    route4 192.168.1.0/24
    inet6 fdcc:a223:f33:5600:b9e8:fe91:f180:c29e/64
    inet6 fe80::a832:3430:5f1f:ed1/64
    route6 fe80::/64
    route6 fdcc:a223:f33:5600::/64
    route6 ff00::/8

wlp3s0: unavailable
    "Realtek RTL8723BE"
    wifi (rtl8723be), mac address, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
    "lo"
    loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
    servers: 192.168.1.1
    interface: enp2s0f2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by updating and installing the realtek firmware. The following is the command :

```
apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-realtek
```

The solution was found in this post [Debian jessie 8.5 doesn't detect wireless](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297585/debian-jessie-8-5-doesnt-detect-wireless)